# pipeline command ./a.out | cat, printf("line\n") in a.out is not excuted and no output

Tags: c, linux, gcc, pipe, pipeline

A very strange thing, a.out just `printf()` a line then go into a dead loop, when a.out is executed single, I can see the line in termial, but if pipeline a.out with cat, then we can't see anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        printf("----------\n");
        while (1) {
                sleep(1000);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

run result

```
$ cc test.c
$ ./a.out 
----------
^C
$ ./a.out | cat
^C
```

if I strace a.out | cat, write(1) system call is not called

```
$ strace ./a.out | cat
execve("./a.out", ["./a.out"], 0x7ffdaa23b200 /* 65 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x5567446dd000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=94391, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 94391, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f977ba22000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200l\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2000480, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f977ba20000
mmap(NULL, 2008696, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f977b835000
mmap(0x7f977b85a000, 1519616, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x25000) = 0x7f977b85a000
mmap(0x7f977b9cd000, 299008, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x198000) = 0x7f977b9cd000
mmap(0x7f977ba16000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1e0000) = 0x7f977ba16000
mmap(0x7f977ba1c000, 13944, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f977ba1c000
close(3)                                = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f977ba21500) = 0
mprotect(0x7f977ba16000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x556743cd8000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f977ba64000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f977ba22000, 94391)           = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x5567446dd000
brk(0x5567446fe000)                     = 0x5567446fe000
nanosleep({tv_sec=1000, tv_nsec=0}, ^C{tv_sec=994, tv_nsec=769383373}) = ? ERESTART_RESTARTBLOCK (Interrupted by signal)
strace: Process 5050 detached
```

if I strace a.out single, then has write(1)

```
$ strace ./a.out 
execve("./a.out", ["./a.out"], 0x7ffe09a7c360 /* 65 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x564b085a8000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=94391, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 94391, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fac37df5000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200l\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2000480, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fac37df3000
mmap(NULL, 2008696, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fac37c08000
mmap(0x7fac37c2d000, 1519616, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x25000) = 0x7fac37c2d000
mmap(0x7fac37da0000, 299008, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x198000) = 0x7fac37da0000
mmap(0x7fac37de9000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1e0000) = 0x7fac37de9000
mmap(0x7fac37def000, 13944, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fac37def000
close(3)                                = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fac37df4500) = 0
mprotect(0x7fac37de9000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x564b076e3000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fac37e37000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fac37df5000, 94391)           = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 2), ...}) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x564b085a8000
brk(0x564b085c9000)                     = 0x564b085c9000
write(1, "----------\n", 11----------
)            = 11
nanosleep({tv_sec=100
```

Why ?

Comment: The stdout stream is probably in fully-buffered mode because the output is going to a pipe instead of a terminal. You can flush the stdout stream after the printf with `fflush(stdout);` to force the buffered output to be written to the pipe.

Comment: Alternatively, you could set the stdout stream to line-buffered mode by calling `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOLBF, 0);` at the start of the program.

Comment: @IanAbbott You should write an answer.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes, when stdout is terminal, it's line buffered, others are block buffered. when I set setlinebuf(stdout); then pipeline act same as terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An output stream can be in one of three different modes, *unbuffered*, *line buffered*, or *fully buffered*. In *unbuffered* mode, output is written immediately. In *line buffered* mode, output is written first to an internal stream buffer until the buffer is full or a newline is written, and then the buffer is flushed to the output. In *fully buffered* mode, the output is written first to an internal stream buffer until the buffer is full, and then the buffer is flushed to the output. (Some implementations may also flush the output at other times, such as when reading input from an interactive device.)

Input streams can also be in the same three modes, and this determines when read input is made available to the caller of functions that read streams.

The implementation initializes the mode of the standard input (`stdin`), standard output (`stdout`), and standard error output (`stderr`) streams before the `main` function is called (or at least before any access to the streams). Under certain circumstances, the implementation is allowed to initialize the standard input or standard output to *fully buffered* mode. The standard input and output streams are initialized to fully buffered mode if and only if the implementation can determine that they are not linked to an interactive device (such as a terminal). (The standard error output stream is never initialized to fully buffered mode.)

Typically, the C runtime library of a POSIX system will call `isatty` on the underlying file descriptors for the standard input and output streams and set the streams to fully buffered mode if `isatty` returns 0. This occurs before the `main` function is called.

When you run "./a.out" with output going to the terminal, the C runtime library determines that output is going to an interactive device and does *not* set `stdout` to fully buffered mode. It will be set to one of the other modes, typically line buffered mode. However, when you run "/a.out" with output going to a pipe, the C runtime library determines that output is *not* going to an interactive device and *does* set `stdout` to fully buffered mode. This is why the output is not written to the pipe immediately.

There are two ways to solve your problem. The first is to change the standard output stream to *line buffered* mode or *unbuffered* mode before the first call to `printf`:

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOLBF, 0); // set standard output to line buffered mode

setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0); // set standard output to unbuffered mode
```

The other way is to to flush the standard output on demand:

```
fflush(stdout); // write buffered standard output contents
```